# Random int generation from existing int

Tags: java, xor, modular

Consider the following int;

```
int start = 287729472784;
```

From that int, I need to create a new int that is only three digits in length, I can use any of the values from 0-9.

However, in order to create the new int, I cannot use any form of already existing random number generators.

I was wondering if it possible to use a combination of *modular*, *xor*, *and*, *bit-shift*- operations to somehow reduce the number down.  Such as xor the last digit with the one before it, but I'm not sure if that is even possible.

Basically I need to create a three digit long int from the starting int, ideally reducing the starting int down to three digits in length.

I hope that makes sense and I'd appreciate any input.

Thanks

Comment: 1. That's not a valid `int` in Java - it's too large. 2. What's your use case? Do you need a different generated three-digit int for each larger integer you pass in? If so, abandon your task - it's impossible (see the [Pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)). If not, a simple modulus operation (like Dirk suggests) will do the job nicely.

Comment: `public string intRand( int input ) { return "004"; }`

Comment: Well the input int I'm actually using is an SHA1 hash converted into an BigInteger and represented as a String.  

The hash is put into a byte[], those bytes are then put into a BigInteger.

I just thought I would start off with a smaller example :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure to understand your need but if your only wish is to generate a 3 digits number from another number maybe that the modulo function could help you :

```
var startNumber = 287729472784;
var modifiedNumber = startNumber % 1000;
```

If you wish a pseudo-randomn modifiedNumber that changes for each generation you can use time in miliseconds :

```
var startNumber = 287729472784;
var modifiedNumber = startNumber * new Date().getTime() % 1000;
```

I hope it'll help.

vaL

Comment: Above code can produce 1 or 2 digits number. You can force a 3 digit number with some code like this :
`code`
if(modifiedNumber < 100) {
modifiedNumber=modifiedNumber*10;
}
if(modifiedNumber < 100) {
modifiedNumber=modifiedNumber*10;
}`code`

Comment: The modulo alone doesn't guarantee an uniform distribution of the numbers. To be exact the numbers 648-1000 will have slightly lower percentage.

Answer (score 1):

Hm. I don't understand the problem, but... `start % 1000` would yield the least significant 3 digits of `start` (though: be careful with negative values)?

Answer (score 1):

The best answer really depends on the use of that final number.  Since SHA1's are reasonably "random" to start with, using % 1000 should suffice -- you'll get a good spread over the range of all possible SHA1 inputs, if all you're looking for is a hash into a table.

However, if you're looking for a transform where the 3 digit number has little or no relationship (meaning, not just a modulo ...) to the input, you'll need some way to bang all the bits into the result.  If that's the case, I'd suggest a transform such as CRC16.  Feed the SHA1 value into your favorite CRC16 routine, then return the modulo 1000 value of that, keeping in mind that some results will show up more often than others.